# Finding an unknown joint PDF?

Tags: probability, continuity, random

> Knowing that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is their joint PDF, and
>   \begin{align}
> f_{X,Y}(x,y)=k, \qquad(0<x<2; 0<y<x)
> \end{align}
>   How can I compute $k$?

Comment: You can find $k$ by knowing and using that the total probability equals $1$.

Comment: \begin{align} \int_0^2\int_{0}^xf_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx \end{align} ?

Comment: Yes, that integral should equal $1$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
& \int_{x = 0}^{2}\int_{y = 0}^{x}f_{X, Y}(x, y)\, dy\, dx = 1 \\
\implies & \int_{x = 0}^{2}\int_{y = 0}^{x} k \, dy\, dx = 1 \\
\implies & k \int_{x = 0}^{2} x \, dx = 1 \\
\implies & k \dfrac{x^{2}}{2}\Bigg\vert_{0}^{2} = 1 \\
\implies & 2k = 1 \\
\implies & k = 0.5
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We know that
$$\int_0^2\int_{0}^{x} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ dy \ dx =1$$
since this is a density.

So
$$\int_0^2\int_{0}^{x} k \ dy \ dx =1$$

$$\int_0^2\big[ky\big]_0^x \ dx =1$$

$$\int_0^2kx \ dx =1$$

$$\left[\frac12kx^2\right]_0^2=1$$
$$2k=1$$
$$k=\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, $0\lt x \lt 2, 0\lt y \lt x$ is a triangle with vertices in $O(0,0), A(2,0), B(2,2)$ and its area is $2$. Thus, the integral of the (constant) PDF over that triangle is $k\cdot \operatorname{Area}(\triangle OAB)$, i.e. $1=2k$, which gives $k=\frac{1}{2}$.